# Extjs 4.1 datefield - Set first and last day of current week

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I try to create a form panel with 2 datefield in **http://jsfiddle.net/uXkNr/**

Here is my items

```
items: [{
        xtype: 'datefield',
        labelWidth: 50,
        format: 'd/m/Y',
        fieldLabel: 'From',
        name: 'from_date',
        value: new Date()  // First day of current week
    }, {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        labelWidth: 50,
        fieldLabel: 'To',
        format: 'd/m/Y',
        name: 'to_date',
        value: new Date()  // Last day of current week
    }]
```

I try to set first and last day of current week. Example

[image]

`today` is: 15/10/2013 (d/m/Y). Then `From` has date is : 14/10/2013 and `To` has date is: 20/10/2013.

Is that possible? How to do that thank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested:

```
var now = new Date(),
    startDay = 1, // monday
    currDay = now.getDay(),
    start = now,
    eDate = Ext.Date,
    sub, end;

eDate.clearTime(now);
if (currDay !== startDay) {
    // Sunday
    if (currDay === 0) {
        sub = 6;
    } else {
        sub = currDay - startDay;
    }
    start = eDate.add(now, eDate.DAY, -sub);
}
end = eDate.add(start, eDate.DAY, 6);
console.log(start, end);
```